# What does "Richten Sie ihr bitte" mean?

Tags: english-to-german, german-to-english, standard-german

In the context of a phone call, one side said:

> Der Termin dauert bis ca. 14h, möchten Sie eine Nachricht hinterlassen?

And the other said:

> Richten Sie ihr bitte, das ich ihr eine E-mail geschickt habe.

The verb *richten* is not clear to me, although Google translated it as

> Please tell her that I have sent her an e-mail.

This sounds okay. But if I translate just *richten*, Google returns *judge*, which then sounds strange.

So, is the phrase correct or should I rephrase it?

Comment: Could you check your source again? As it is, the sentence is incorrect as it is missing a word.

Comment: It must be "*Richten* Sie ihr bitte *aus*, ...", which (in this context) means "tell her" in the sense of "forward the information to her". The verb is "ausrichten" which gets split into "richten ... aus"

Comment: @Bodo Please don't answer in comments.

Answer (score 8):

The sentence is incomplete and contains mistakes. It should be

> Richten Sie ihr bitte *aus*, *<s>das</s> dass* ich ihr eine E-Mail geschickt *<s>have</s> habe*.
>
> <sub>(Please tell her that I sent her an e-mail.)</sub>

The verb in question is not *richten* (to judge), but *ausrichten* (to message/ to tell). It is [separable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separable_verb#German), which is why the prefix *aus-* is located at the end of the main clause.